# How to avoid kotlin files with Findbugs

Tags: findbugs, kotlin

I'm integrating findbugs in a mixed java/kotlin project. However, as findbugs acts on the generated jar it is finding bugs related to classes generated through kotlin file.

Is there any way to avoid checks on these classes?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filter based on the `<Source>` filter type.

> This element matches warnings associated with a particular source file. The name attribute is used to specify the exact or regex match pattern for the source file name.

```xml
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Source name="~.*\.kt"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

See:  [documentation for FindBugs filters](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)
and  [name matching details](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html#d0e2197)

Answer (score 0):

I think filter should help in many cases:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Class name="*Kt"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

I'm not sure that this filter is right, but you should got idea.

[Documentation.](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)

Comment: That will only catch some Kotlin classes that are created by the compiler, not all.  Unless they have common package names, or different module output paths, this would be tough to do.

Comment: For sure Source is better